# Preserve text layers when exporting to PSD in GIMP?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, export

I have a bunch of old xcf files on my computer I'd really like to export to PSD after moving my workstation over to all Adobe products.

However, I'm noticing that when I export my xcf files to PSD, the text layers get rasterized and become uneditable.

Is there a way to resolve this by changing settings or using a plugin, or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

There is currently no way to do this with GIMP, you are out of luck.

Longer answer:

PSD export is handled by a plug-in. By improving that plug-in, you or someone else can add text layer export to this plug-in. GIMP is Free Software, so contributions by people who need a specific feature are expected.